# Questions about DocuSign with Salesforce CPQ

Tags: lightning, cpq, docusign, quote-template

The relevant apps (DocuSign for Salesforce CPQ and Salesforce CPQ) are already installed in our dev sandbox.

The connection between DocuSign and Salesforce including the setup of template was already done by a previous team. Currently, from a quote, we are able to use the feature "Generate Document" then "Send to DocuSign", which sends the document correctly to the customer "Primary contact" field from the quote.

We are having issues to customize/fix the integration to complete the business rules.
Online documentation is not very precise for these use cases.

In DocuSign portal, the template is setup to have 2 recipients:

1. Role "Customer" [needs to sign]
2. Role "Sender" [needs to sign]

The sender is the sales person in Salesforce who will click on the button "Send to DocuSign".
But when testing without any "DocuSign Recipients" in the quote template in Salesforce, only the customer is receiving the quote document for signature. Now, when the customer opens the document, then an email is sent to the sender notifying him that the customer is viewing the document. The issue is once the customer signs the document, it gets completed without requiring the sender to sign as well.

We also need to include some merged fields from Salesforce within the quote template, whereby the field must be defaulted with values from Salesforce but the customer must be allowed to edit some of these merged fields.

**Things already tried**

- Followed the documentation [Set Up DocuSign Recipients for CPQ Quotes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_docusign_recip.htm&type=5) by adding DocuSign Recipients with Role "Customer" and another one "Sender", but doing so does not send document at all. The log failures from DocuSign portal does not provide much detail `SalesForceIntegration failed, SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c failed, message: Unable to update SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c, additional info: ErrorCode = CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, fields =`
- [How to create merge fields with DocuSign for CPQ setup](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000Dq4uQAC) is a useful post, but we are not able to identify where exactly is the settings "merge with Salesforce setting turned on by DocuSign" and also where to have "Set as Salesforce merge field" option
- From DocuSign help guide, [Create Merge Fields](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/dfs-admin-guide-merge-fields-admin) article refers to "DocuSign for Salesforce" app and "DocuSign Admin" tab, both of which are not available in the packages installed. A "DocuSign Tag" object exist in our salesforce org, but no field called "Relate to Salesforce" can be found

**Questions**

1. How do we setup 2 signers for DocuSign and ensure both are notified and have signed before document is considered completed?
2. How can we add a Salesforce merged field within the quote template and make it editable in the document?
3. How to make make a merged field conditionally editable in the document (for e.g if value from salesforce is empty, then make it editable) ?
4. Is it possible to include quote related files in salesforce as attachment to the email sent by DocuSign requesting signature of the quote by the 2 signers ?

Can someone who has worked with CPQ and DocuSign give us some pointers how we can go about the above?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I think you should get in touch with package vendor support.

Comment: @rahulgawale Yes already contacted the package vendor support, still waiting for an answer. I was hoping to get a faster and helpful answer here in SFSE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**

Found workaround solution to each of the questions and also got support from DocuSign to activate merged fields.

> 1. How do we setup 2 signers for DocuSign and ensure both are notified and have signed before document is considered completed?

In DocuSign portal, the signing order must be set for "customer" and "sender".

In Salesforce, under the Quote template, DocuSign Recipients records must be created with exact same role name and order number, where role type for "customer" must be "signer" and role type of "sender" must be "sender". Even if both will eventually sign in this use case.

> 2. How can we add a Salesforce merged field within the quote template and make it editable in the document?

First, DocuSign support must activate the feature required to create Salesforce merged fields. 
Then appexchange [DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001taX4EAI) must also be installed, even if DocuSign for Salesforce CPQ is already installed.

Connection between DocuSign and Salesforce must be initiated via the DocuSign admin tab, of the **DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce** application.

Merged fields with writeback to salesforce, can then be created either from custom tags from DocuSign Admin tab (Salesforce) or from the DocuSign template using merge fields section.

I chose to create the fields from DocuSign, by doing Edit template, next to modify the template content.
"Merge fields" options appear in the left side bar of options: Standard Fields, Custom Fields, Merged Fields...

Click on the + sign to create a new merged field.

Search for salesforce fields starting from Quote Document, then drill down to quote and other related relationship field.

[image]

> 3. How to make make a merged field conditionally editable in the document (for e.g if value from salesforce is empty, then make it editable) ?

Once merged field is added, then conditions can be added via the right sidebar option "conditional logic".

More info here: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-conditional-fields

> 4. Is it possible to include quote related files in salesforce as attachment to the email sent by DocuSign requesting signature of the quote by the 2 signers ?

This is related to Salesforce CPQ package and currently files cannot be attached to the email sent.

But workaround is to use "Additional Document" object and add additional files to the quote PDF itself that is sent for signature. "Additional Document", is a related object to CPQ Quote and for each record added, the external id field must match with the attachment/file found on quote.

Either use attachment file id or content document id as external id (Salesforce CRM content must be enabled to use content document id)

Note, additional document is restricted to PDF files only: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_add_pdfs_to_quote_docs.htm&type=5

We finally did a trigger on content objects to automatically handle creation/deletion of records in additional document whenever a new pdf was created/deleted to the quote.
The files can then be selected to be added to quote document sent for signature.
The additional documents will be embedded at the end the quote document received by recipients.

[image]